# Handling Navigation Drawer views Activity error

Tags: java

this error keeps happening every time a run the default navigation drawer views activity  " Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)" how should i solve this error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.